# async await not deploying in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

`firebase deploy` is giving me this error message:

```
        async function asyncFunction() {
              ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

Here's my code:

```
async function asyncFunction() {
      await getText2Speech(word, 'mp3', 'es-ES_EnriqueVoice')
    }
asyncFunction();
```

`getText2Speech` is a 75-line function that runs perfectly when I call it without `async` or `await`.

I have the Node.js 8 runtime in my `functions/package.json`:

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

[image]

I have Node up to date on my computer:

```
node -v
v11.2.0
```

It seems odd that the unexpected token is `function`, not `async`. It seems that `firebase deploy` recognizes `async` but I have the syntax wrong? `es-lint` can't find anything wrong with my code.

Could the problem be this:

```
npm list --depth 0 -g

├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase-admin@6.2.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: firebase-admin@~6.0.0, required by firebase-functions@2.1.0
```

If I roll back to `firebase-admin@~6.0.0` will `async await` work?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that something was pointing to eslint v4.5.0, which doesn't support ES2017. I had eslint v5.9.0 installed but `eslint -v` always returned v4.5.0. I used `find . -name 'eslint'` to remove every copy of eslint, there were lots of versions, all other my computer. `npm uninstall -g eslint` doesn't get every copy of eslint. When `eslint -v` returned nothing then `firebase deploy` worked.

Comment: Hi @Thomas! Would you mind accepting your own answer? It will make it more visible and help other users with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks ^^!

Comment: The solution worked for a day and then stopped working. On my other computer async/await deployed to Firebase for a couple weeks, then today it stopped deploying. I'm baffled...

Answer (score 1):

`async/await` was deploying on my other computer, then today it stopped deploying. I checked the `package.json` in the `functions` folder on both computers, and both were missing

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

Adding this line, both computers now deploy `async/await`. I don't know how this object dropped out of the `package.json` file, and I don't know if this fix will continue to work, but I'll cross my fingers!